# Get-AzureVM returning null despite having VMs under the subscription

Tags: powershell, azure

I was working on a script which I have downloaded from the gallery to stop all VMs running in a subscription. This was running perfectly until last week, but when I ran it yesterday, it couldnt find any VM in my subscription (VMs are there in my sub and running). Script is below:

```
workflow Stop-AllAzureVM
{   
    # Add the credential used to authenticate to Azure. 
    # TODO: Fill in the -Name parameter with the Name of the Automation     PSCredential asset
    # that has access to your Azure subscription.  "myPScredName" is your asset name that reflects an OrgID user
    # like "someuser@somewhere.onmicrosoft.com" that has Co-Admin rights to your subscription.
    $Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "myPsCred"

    # Connect to Azure
    Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred

    # Select the Azure subscription you want to work against
    # TODO: Fill in the -SubscriptionName parameter with the name of your Azure subscription
    Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "MySubs"


    # Get all Azure VMs in the subscription that are not stopped and deallocated, and shut them down
    # all at once.
    $VMs = Get-AzureVM | where-object -FilterScript {$_.status -ne 'StoppedDeallocated'}
    if (!$VMs)
    {
        Write-Output "No VM running at the moment"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "VM(s) found running, proceeding for shutdown"
    }
    foreach -parallel ($vm in $VMs)
    {       
        $stopRtn = Stop-AzureVM -Name $VM.Name -ServiceName $VM.ServiceName -force -ea SilentlyContinue
        $count=1
        if(($stopRtn.OperationStatus) -ne 'Succeeded')
        {
            do{
                    Write-Output "Failed to stop $($VM.Name). Retrying in 60 seconds..."
                    sleep 60
                    $stopRtn = Stop-AzureVM -Name $VM.Name -ServiceName $VM.ServiceName -force -ea SilentlyContinue
                    $count++
                }
                while(($stopRtn.OperationStatus) -ne 'Succeeded' -and $count -lt 5)

        }

        if($stopRtn){Write-Output "Stop-AzureVM cmdlet for $($VM.Name) $($stopRtn.OperationStatus) on attempt number $count of 5."}
    }
```

}

This script always prints "No VM running at the moment"

I tried Get-AzureVM without any condition also but the result was same.

I am not sure if something has changed in past couple of weeks which is resulting in this issue.

**Update-1:**
I tried adding below commands in script:

```
$VMs = Get-AzureVM
$subscriptions = Get-AzureSubscription
Write-Output "Found [$($subscriptions.Count)] subscriptions accessible to user"
Write-Output "Found [$($VMs.Count)] VMs in Subscription"
```

and I got below output:

Found [] subscriptions accessible to user
Found [0] VMs in Subscription
No VM running at the moment

So it looks like something weird had happened in my automation account and I dont seem to have any clue about it!

Comment: Try to select your subscription using the select-azuresubscription cmdlet

Comment: @jisaaj it is already there - selecting "MySubs"

Comment: @user2006769, what happens when you strip the "workflow" part and run the script locally, with the latest Azure PowerShell Module installed on your machine ?

Comment: @astaykov I ran the command Get-AzureVM locally with same subscription and it works good there. As I said, this was running fine under Azure Automation couple of weeks back and I didnt modify anything there and despite that fact its not running today.

Comment: do you locally authenticate with absolutey the same Azure AD account? If not - try to use the **same** account locally, as you use in Automation. And please do `Clear-AzureProfile` before you test. The Azure AD account you use for automation might have been expired and requires password change, which would cause your workbook to stop running.

Comment: I tried resetting the password of automation credential, nothing changed. Then I tried creating a new automation account and copy pasted same runbook in it and it is working now. Looks like some bug in Azure. I'll report it to MS. Thanks guys for helpful comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To all who are facing this issue, not sure if this is the right way to fix this but at least as a workaround, I tried creating a new automation account and copy pasted same runbook in it and it is working fine for me.